# In InDesign CS6, how do I get single words in italics into the header by using running headers and character styles

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, character-styles

First, I want to apologize if this question has been asked before, but since I am no native speaker I don't even know what words exactly I have to ask for. Maybe then you can help me by posting the link to the question?

My problem is as follows:

In the document I'm working on in InDesign CS6, I have to make headers for each page containing of the first and second order headlines (e.g. "1. Introduction"; "1.1 How it works"). Now, in the headlines there's one word showing up from time to time that's written in italics, in the middle of the sentence: "1.1 How it *really* works".

The headlines are defined by paragraph styles, but for the headers I use character styles because some of the headlines are too long: Headline: "1.1 How it *really* works using the magic InDesign help forums"; header: "1.1 How it *really* works".

Now my problem is that no matter what I do, the word "really" doesn't show up in italics in the header. Maybe it has to do with nested formats, but I don't understand that very much, and from what I understand, you can't use single expressions to change formats in nested formats, and so saying "Please change from normal to italics when the word 'really' appears" won't work.

Can you help me with this?

The only solution I have is to use new masters for every time this occurs and write the header by hand, not using text variables. Which is significantly more work, and which is also insecure, because if there's some shifting of text, the headers may end up on the wrong page, which also has to be controlled again and again.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Best, Sascha